# Refactoring in PyCharm: How to extract a method?

Tags: refactoring, pycharm

Everytime I select a block of code and choose Refactor This > Extract > Method, the pop up window arrives with "nothing to show" in the parameter field. Consider the following program:

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = a + b

print(c)
```

I select the line *c = a + b*, and choose Refactor This > Extract > Method.  I expected the popup box parameters field to include at least *a* and *b*, but instead:  "nothing to show".  How is this supposed to work?

Does the example in [the doc section Extract Method](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/extract-method.html) really work?  What was selected in "Before" in order to arrive at "After".  There's no *d* in "Before", so I suspect a typo...

[PyCharm 4.04 on OS X 10.9.5]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example you quote is performed in the context of a class. It works fine for me with Pycharm 4.0.4 on OS X 10.7

[image]

The same action in the context of a "script" will bring a different result though, since it seems Pycharm then relies more on the namespace, as you may have observed already if you accepted the refactoring:

```
a = 1
b = 2

def method_name():
    global c
    c = a + b

method_name()
print(c)
```

Which works, although not necessarily useful in that case.

Lastly, the `d` variable you mention seems to have been extracted, using another refactoring, from

```
math.sqrt(b**2 - 4*a*c)
```

I agree this is not the point of the doc page and should probably have been avoided.